# Find the parameter values for which the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^p - x}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was trying to solve this question but I was really stuck on trying to find a function to compare the integrand of this integral to.
Can anyone help me solve this using the Convergence Comparison Test?

$$\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^p - x}dx$$

For which p values does this converge, and how do you prove it? 
The correct answer should be for no p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\frac1{x^p-x}}{\frac1{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac {x-1}{x^p-x}=\frac1{p-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, but doesnt the limit need to converge to a final limit that does not equal to 0? Thats what I have been taught...

Comment: It follows from what I did that $\frac1{x^p-x}$ is bigger than $\frac1x$ near $0$. So, since the integral of $\frac1x$ diverges, then so does your integral.

Comment: But, the limit we are checking is near 1 from the right, not near 0... and the following integral does not diverge for any finite value b:
$$\int_1^b \frac1{x} dx$$

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I've edited my answer. I hope that everyting is correct now.

Comment: I would assume the limit  is $\frac1{p-1}$.

Comment: @user But it isn't.

Comment: I have checked. The limit is still $\frac1{p-1}$.

Comment: Take $p=2$. Then$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac1{x+1}=\frac12\neq\frac11.$$

Comment: It should be $x^2-x$ in the denominator, not $x^2-1$.

Comment: @user Right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you maybe explain how did you calculate the limit of
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{x-1}{x^p-x}$$
I'm afraid I wasn't taught how to divide such a polynomial...

Comment: This is the inverse of $\lim_{x\to1^+}x\frac{x^{p-1}-1}{x-1}$, which is $1$ times the derivative at $1$ of the function $x\mapsto x^{p-1}$. So, this limit is $p-1$, and therefore the original limit is $\frac1{p-1}$.

Comment: Amazing way to look at it! I also forgot that you could just apply L'Hospital's rule here. Thanks alot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.